# How to customized seek bar like use an image as seek bar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, wpf-controls

I have a image like:

[image]

I want to use it as seek bar of music player.

Can any one please suggest me how can I implement a seek bar like above image.

My plan is base bar will be same image with opacity of 0.5 and progress bar will be same with opacity of 1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To implement a seek bar like that you can [re-template a `Slider` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/slider-styles-and-templates#slider-controltemplate-example). You will also need to extend `Border` or similar control to use above image as `Background` or simply draw this line using `Polyline` as track-bar.

**For example:**

```
public class ZigZagBorder : Border
{
    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);

        var zigzag = new Polyline()
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
            StrokeThickness = 2
        };
        var points = new PointCollection();
        for (int i = 0; i < ActualWidth - 5; i = i + 5)
        {
            points.Add(
                new Point(
                    i,
                    (i % 2 == 0 ? 5 : 10)
                 ));
        }

        zigzag.Points = points;
        RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(this, EdgeMode.Aliased);
        Child = zigzag;
    }
}
```

**Sample usage would look like:**

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="LeftRepeatButton" TargetType="RepeatButton">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="RightRepeatButton" TargetType="RepeatButton">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                    <Border  Background="White" Opacity="0.75" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="SliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Path Data="M 0 0 L 8 0 L 4 6 Z"  Stroke="Black" Margin="-2,0,0,0" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Black"></Path>
                        <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="3" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="2,0,0,0" StrokeDashArray="1.5,1.5"></Line>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Slider"  TargetType="Slider">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Row="0" Placement="Top" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <local:ZigZagBorder x:Name="TrackBackground" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" />
            <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track" Margin="0,-2,0,0"  >
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource LeftRepeatButton}"  Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}" Margin="0,-5,0,0" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource RightRepeatButton}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Row="2" Placement="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement"  Value="TopLeft">
                <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility"  Value="Visible" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
                <Setter TargetName="BottomTick"  Property="Visibility"  Value="Visible" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
                <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Setter TargetName="BottomTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="Horizontal_Slider" TargetType="Slider">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="200" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Slider}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="Panel1" Margin="20">
    <Slider Style="{StaticResource Horizontal_Slider}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TickFrequency="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"></Slider>
</Grid>
```

This sample controls the opacity on progress/seek bar by modifying these values in `RepeatButton`(s) templates - i.e. LeftRepeatButton, and RightRepeatButton

[image: output]

References:

1. [Draw zig-zag line using poly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706283/wpf-polygon-and-poly)
2. [Custom track/slider template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508167/track-bar-slider-template-for-wpf)